# How can I make image a specific shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photo-editing

I really need some help with turning this image from a square portrait image, into an image of this exact shape and size.

[image]

I need to turn this picture above, into this shape and size. It needs the exact same size, too, but I am unsure how to do this using GIMP/Photoshop.

Can someone help me, please?

[image]

The dimension of the picture above is: Dimensions: 1206 by 1094 pixels

However, I am super confused how to get my van picture, into the shape and size of the bottom picture.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a layer mask in GIMP (also possible in Photoshop).

In GIMP use the Paths Tool to draw a shape, hit Enter to turn it into a selection

Then hit the layer mask icon, and choose "Selection".

Example

[image]

Comment: If you know, in Photoshop, can we change path color (while drawing Path) and weight just like this?

Comment: @Vikas - not as far as I know. It would be in the preferences if there were such an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Photoshop:** Create a new document. If you want it as same size as your reference image, you can create it accordingly. I've used same size.

1. Paste the reference image in a bottom layer and lock it. Then use Pen tool *(you can use another method given in the end to make a path)* to draw a path (hold shift for straight lines while drawing paths)
2. Click *Shape* button to convert it into solid shape (make sure *Combined Shapes* is selected, which is right next to *Shape* button)
3. Paste your image in a new layer above this shape layer, convert it into smart object (smart object is optional, I use it so it doesn't pixelate accidently while scaling up and down) and make a clipping mask (you can do this by holding Alt and hovering between shape layer and your image layer in layers panel and then Click)
4. Resize your image as you like.
5. Once satisfied, group both shape and image layers so you can move it easily without moving both layers individually  (you still can adjust your shape if you have to)
6. Hide the locked layer.

[image]

I'm not really sure if you need the padding on top and right side of your image. If you don't need you can align the group to right-top.  Like this:

[image]

---

Using quick selection for creating the path for this particular image:

[image]

Then you can move the newly created shape layer for alignment.